24.10 LTS crashing on Raspberry Pi 5
I had flashed Ubuntu 24.10 LTS (Tried on 3 different computers, excluding network install) onto a 128 GB SanDisk Ultra Class 10 Micro SDXC Card. The OS just crashes on startup. You turn it on, the fan of the cooler spins for a bit, and it turns off and shows red LED. Anybody know how to solve this? If this does not make sense, NOTE: I am running this on a Raspberry Pi 5.

24.10 is NOT an LTS release. What method did you use to create the bootable SD card?

you should find this Ubuntu Downloads aricle helpful

Richard Knepp, seems that there is something wrong with my Imager. I created the same post on Reddit, and another person was having the same problem. He told me to download the iso from the Ubuntu sit and then flash the downloaded .img using Imager; it worked for him apparently. I can only try tomorrow though, as I don't have access to a Windows PC right now.

Graham, thank you, I definitely did find it useful.
